# Enviar datos desde un formulario en JS a un Controlador de Laravel y hacer un update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, php5

tengo una página que mediante AJAX usando JS hago una llamada a un controlador y le envio los datos del fomulario (esto funciona correctamente, recibo bien los datos en el controlador)

```
$(".btn-submit").click(function(e){

e.preventDefault();
var codigo_promocion = $("input[name=codigo_promocion]").val();
var descuento = $("input[name=descuento]").val();
var descripcion = $("input[name=descripcion]").val();

$.ajax({

    type:'PUT',
    url:'/api/promociones/' + id_site_promocion ,
    data: {
        codigo_promocion: codigo_promocion,
        descuento : descuento,
        descripcion : descripcion,
    },
    success:function(data){
        $('.btn-submit').prop('disabled', false);
    },
    error:function (data) {
        $('.btn-submit').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});

});
```

El problema lo tengo en el controlador, hago lo siguiente recibo los datos de la request y intento hacer un update me esta dando error en las últimas lineas cuando hace el "update" si por ejemplo el usuario no rellena el campo descripción luego no se envia des del JS al controlador y al intentar hacer update me da fallo.

```
/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory|\Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

    $promocionExists = Promocion::find($id);

    if (null === $promocionExists) {
        return response('Promocion no válida',404);
    }

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'codigo_promocion' => 'max:255',
        'descuento' => 'max:255',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response(['errors' => $validator->messages()->all()],400);
    }


    Promocion::find($id)
        ->update([
            'codigo_promocion' => $request->get('codigo_promocion'),
            'descuento' => $request->get('descuento'),
            'descripcion' => $request->get('descripcion'),
        ]);

    return response('Promoción modificada correctamente',200);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que la falla es porque no existe el parámetro en el request, si es así lo puedes manejar de esta manera:

```
if(isset($request->get('descripcion'))){
    'descripcion' => $request->get('descripcion'),
}else{
    'descripcion' => '', // o null
}
```